# JodaTime confused about TimeZone offset

Tags: android, datetime, android-jodatime

I receive a Date String like `"2018-06-21T13:30:00Z"`
I parse it with the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`

I am in GMT+2 and the result looks like `2018-06-21T15:30:00.000+02:00`
while i expected it to look like this `2018-06-21T13:30:00.000+02:00`

Is the offset supposed to be already applied in the `HH:mm:ss` part of the Result?

Code

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parseDateTime("2018-06-21T13:30:00Z")
```

joda:2.9.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the date time given is in the local time of +02:00.

From [ISO 8601 Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) *Time offsets from UTC*:

> The following times all refer to the same moment: "18:30Z", "22:30+04", "1130−0700", and "15:00−03:30". Nautical time zone letters are not used with the exception of Z. To calculate UTC time one has to subtract the offset from the local time, e.g. for "15:00−03:30" do 15:00 − (−03:30) to get 18:30 UTC.

So for your case: `2018-06-21T15:30:00.000+02:00` means 15:30 - 02:00 so a UTC of 13:30